# Joining on incorrect data using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

So I have a lookup table like this:

```
ID Descrip
11 Apples
12 Bananas
13 Grapes
14 Cherries
```

However my data looks like this:

```
col
11
13
11
12
12
Apples
Cherries
Bananas
Ba_nanas
14
```

So I want to match `col` to the lookup and have data like this:

```
col    Descrip
11     Apples
13     Grapes
11     Apples
12     Bananas
12     Bananas
11     Apples
14     Cherries
12     Bananas
NA     NA
14     Cherries
```

So to note, if there is no match in either, both should be nulled out, like `Ba_nanas`

I tried the following and it works, but only in one direction.....

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(col = ifelse(nchar(col)>2, NA ,col))
  left_join(lookup, by =c("col" = "ID"))
```

I would really like to stick to revolving around replacing when `nchar > 2` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. You can set this `base R` approach to make a double match and then based on results conditionate to extract the desired values using `ifelse()`. Here the code (First test with the data you shared):

```
#Code format vars
df$col1 <- as.numeric(df$col)
Keys$ID <- as.character(Keys$ID)
#Match
df$M1 <- Keys[match(df$col,Keys$ID),"Descrip"]
df$M2 <- Keys[match(df$col,Keys$Descrip),"ID"]
#Format new vars
df$Var <- ifelse(!is.na(df$M1),df$M1,
                 ifelse(!is.na(df$M2),df$col,NA))
df$id <- ifelse(!is.na(df$col1),df$col1,
                ifelse(!is.na(df$M2),df$M2,NA))
#Select
df2 <- df[,c('id','Var')]
```

Output:

```
     id      Var
1    11   Apples
2    13   Grapes
3    11   Apples
4    12  Bananas
5    12  Bananas
6    11   Apples
7    14 Cherries
8    12  Bananas
9  <NA>     <NA>
10   14 Cherries
```

Some data used:

```
#Data 1
df <- structure(list(col = c("11", "13", "11", "12", "12", "Apples", 
"Cherries", "Bananas", "Ba_nanas", "14")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

#Data 2
Keys <- structure(list(ID = c("11", "12", "13", "14"), Descrip = c("Apples", 
"Bananas", "Grapes", "Cherries")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```